# How to convert date-time string in the form (yyyymmddhhss) to dd/mm/yyyy in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date

I am consuming an API that returns a date-time field in form of a string YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. 
For the sake of readability for the users who need to see it in a readable form, how can I convert this into dd/mm/yyyy and display the time separately in the form hh:mm:ss?

For example: '20201127100602' convert to: Date: 27/11/2020 , Time: 10:06:02

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are [many duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+reformat+date), please make an attempt at an answer before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) module (an evolution of Moment.js), it will do this kind of thing very nicely:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const timestamp = "20201127075434";
const dt = DateTime.fromFormat(timestamp, "yyyyMMddHHmmss");

console.log("dd/mm/yyyy:", dt.toFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
console.log("hh:mm:ss:", dt.toFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-OyrI249ZRX2hY/1CAD+edQR90flhuXqYqjNYFJAiflsKsMxpUYg5kbDDAVA8Vp0HMlPG/aAl1tFASi1h4eRoQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You could also use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```js
const timestamp = "20201127075434";
const dt = moment(timestamp, "YYYYMMDDHHmmSS");

console.log("Moment.js:");
console.log("dd/mm/yyyy:", dt.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
console.log("hh:mm:ss", dt.format("HH:mm:SS"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using nodeJS, is luxon a library available in npm?

Comment: Thanks very much. I had moment.js but didn't know I could do that. :D

Comment: Oh yes it is indeed. I've added an example in Moment.js as well. You could use either, I'm liking Luxon now since Moment.js is _kinda_ legacy - "We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done." But Moment.js will be fine to use for a long time yet!

Comment: There's no need to parse the string to a Date or use a date library, especially when the OP hasn't tagged or asked for a library.

Comment: I'd take that point RobG. In this instance, one could simply parse the string, then compose the desired formats. However, using a library gives us a flexible solution that can give us a variety of output formats. One could also convert timezones, for example if the Date is in UTC and we wish to display in another zone.

Answer (score 1):

if you're date format is fixed 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' then, you could right your own function to get the date time, here is sample code:

```js
var str =  '20201127100602';
var dd = str.match(/.{1,2}/g);

var date = dd[3]+'/'+dd[2]+'/'+dd[0]+dd[1];
console.log(date);

var time = dd[4]+':'+dd[5]+':'+dd[6];
console.log(time)
```

Here is one more way to readable code suggested by @RobG

```js
    var str =  '20201127100602';
    let [c, y, m, d, hr, min, sec] = str.match(/\d\d/g);
    console.log(d+'/'+m+'/'+c+y);
    console.log(hr+':'+min+':'+sec)
```

****Note - Recommended only when date format is fixed**

Comment: I think `let [c, y, m, d, hr, min, sec] =  str.match(/\d\d/g)` is simpler. :-) The format must be known to reliably parse it anyway.

Comment: your are right, thanks for the suggestion.